# Get data from Google Analytics by using Node

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using node js, I have to get google analytics data for example page views etc. from where I have to start coding please share any example also. I am sharing the code but in this code, access token expire in every 15 min.

Code

```js
var axios = require('axios');
exports.googledata = async (req, res) => {
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?access_token=xxxxx&ids=ga%3A214170689&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Faccounts%2Fregistration%2F&start-date=2022-01-01&end-date=today',
    headers: {}
  };
  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Explore specialized packages that use reporting api. There are a few good ones for Node.

Comment: Access Tokens are valid for 1 hour only. After that you have to either regenerate or refresh them using Refresh Token. You can refer to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) for more details.